# why LinkedBlockingQueue's take() method is putting thread to sleep state when its size() > 0?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blocking

I have a LinkedBlockingQueue and before calling its take() method I check if it's size() > 0. But my thread's gets stuck when its take method is called.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<DTO> tmpQueue = A.Map.get(Manager.ID);
if(tmpQueue!=null && tmpQueue.size()>0)
{
    while(tmpQueue.size()>0)
    {

        DTO tmpDTO = tmpQueue.take();  // LinkedBlockingQueue<MediaDataDTO> tmpQueue
        // tmpQueue is a local variable and only this thread is using it now;               


    }
}
```

If I take a jstack of the process then I find that thread is stuck when

```
DTO tmpDTO = tmpQueue.take();
```

like has been called.

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x00000007275f1328> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
```

It does not happen all the time but it happened and I saw this from jstack's log.

I know I probably should use poll() not take() in my scenario but I would like to understand why this heppened?

Comment: maybe another thread has removed the element between the condition on `size > 0` and `take()`?

Comment: Actually, the way the code is structured only one thread can run these code. This is why it is freaking me out.

Comment: Ditto what @assylias said. You can build application entirely out of thread-safe classes, but that will not necessarily make the application itself thread-safe. The comment in your code snippet says, "...only this thread is using it now," but where is the guarantee of that? The comment also says, "`tmpQueue` is a local variable," but that fact won't prevent other threads from using the same queue object.

Comment: Based on how `LinkedBlockingQueue` is written, `await` is only called from `take` if the queue is empty. So I don't see another option...

Comment: And as @jameslarge pointed out, the queue may be a local variable but it's accessible via the map which seems to be global so there is nothing preventing another thread from doing the same...

Comment: tmpQueue is local reference not local variable like you have said in the code comment. There is chance some other thread is working on the thread and the queue has become empty just after if was satisfied and before your take is called.

Comment: @Tharun `tmpQueue` absolutely _is_ a variable. Every variable in Java either holds a _primitive value_, or it holds an object reference. `tmpQueue` is a local variable that holds a reference to a `LinkedBlockingQueue<DTO>` instance. @Al-Alamin, No other thread can access or assign `tmpQueue` besides the thread that created it, but that does not prevent other threads from creating their own local variables that refer to the same `LinkedBlockingQueue` object.

Comment: @jameslarge I just come to say as he is not creating a new Queue but getting it from a Map "A.Map.get(Manager.ID);" which could be shared and another reference may point to and work on thhe same Queue. I think i made my point clear.